# How to force Firefox to open a file which does not have a .txt extension as if it did have one?

Tags: firefox

I have files which are just plain text, but have extension which is not `.txt`. Lets say the extension is `.abc`.

When I click on a link that points to such a file, such as `file.abc`, I'd like Firefox to open the file as if it was `file.txt` (i.e. open it inside Firefox, listed inside Firefox itself, just like what happens when I click on `file.txt`) instead of it asking how if I want to save it or open it, and then I have to go select the application to open it with, such Notepad or whatever.

I went to Tools → Options → Applications, but did not know what to do.

**Added**: Based on the comment below and the answer so far, it looks I did not explain myself well.

I want Firefox to open the file as if the file had `.txt` extension. When you click on a link in Firefox which has `.txt`, what does Firefox do? It does not open the file in Notepad or whatever, it opens right there, inside the browser, showing the listing of the file. I want to the same to happen when `.abc` extension.

I do not want to go around mess up with the Windows OS for this.

Comment: If you are in Windows, rt click file.abc and change the properties of it to `open file using` option to firefox and its solved

Comment: I did that. Now when I click on the file, firefox keeps making a new window opening a new firefox window with the same popup asking me what I want to use to open the file with. So your solution does not work at all.

Comment: Possible same on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/43379/force-view-text-file-instead-of-download-in-firefox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the `mymeTypes.rdf` in your Firefox profile (while Firefox is not running) to add extension-to-type mappings mapping the extensions in question to "text/plain".  Unfortunately, Firefox has no user interface exposed for this operation....

I'd make a backup of the file before editing; the syntax is a bit finicky.

Comment: thank you. That was the correct way to do it. This way, only firefox is affected, and I can still double click on the file from windows, and the other application still opens it as I wanted. So your answer is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: User [oislek](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1033748/oislek) added [this Mozilla.org link](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file), related to this answer.

Answer (score 28):

For a quick solution, you can add `view-source:` before the url. This also works in Chrome.

Comment: I prepended this to the url, it simply caused firefox to convert it to a google search instead, which was not helpful

Answer (score 14):

You should try this addon: [Open in Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-browser/).

> It offers the possibility to display documents in the browser window.

[image: Firefox's File Open Dialog Box]

Comment: This app says it accesses all your data in browser..!!! Probably that is why firefox initially prevents from adding it showing an alert..!! So isn't this safe ?

Comment: There is an explanation why it needs those permissions here https://github.com/Rob--W/open-in-browser/issues/62 . Also this addon is open source so you check what is does by yourself. :)

Comment: Still works great!

Comment: This will just cause firefox to reprompt to open the file with an app in a new tab, and if you click "Open with browser" too much then it'll just start spawning infinite tabs trying to open the file.

Answer (score 5):

for nightly 26 alpha, opening .java files as text/plain

`find ~/.mozilla -name mimeTypes.rdf`

add children to node /RDF:RDF

```
<RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:text/plain"
               NC:value="text/plain"
               NC:editable="true"
               NC:fileExtensions="java"
               NC:description="Java source file">
  <NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:handler:text/plain"/>
</RDF:Description>
```

Answer (score 2):

For reference, here is a relevant Firefox bug:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196078

---

- Title: Browser should render unrecognized text/* as text/plain
- Date: 2003-03-05
- Type: defect
- Status: NEW

---

> User-Agent:       Mozilla/5.0 Galeon/1.2.7 (X11; Linux i686; U;) Gecko/20030131
> Build Identifier: Mozilla/5.0 Galeon/1.2.7 (X11; Linux i686; U;) Gecko/20030131
>
> RFC 2046, 4.1 says of the "text" type:
>
> In the absence of appropriate interpretation software, it is reasonable
> to show subtypes of "text" to the user, while it is not reasonable to do
> so with most nontextual data.
>
> Unless the user has associated it with an application, or elected to save it to
> disc by default, the browser should display arbitrary text/* types as text/plain.
>
> Reproducible: Always
>
> Steps to Reproduce:

And another bug linked to the above one:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57342

---

- Title: Add "View as Text/HTML/..." option for unknown mime content-type
- Date: 2000-10-19
- Type: enhancement
- Status: NEW

---

> It appears that there is no way to tell mozilla to display documents of type
> text/* (other than text/plain) to display right in the browser window.  I would
> like to browse source code files (text/x-java, for example) right in the browser,
> but instead I am presented with an open-using/save panel.  Neither of these two
> options is the desired choice.  I could not find a way to tell mozilla to treat
> text/x-java the same way it treats text/plain.

Answer (score -2):

Navigate to Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Default Programs (if you are on win7) and click on "choose default for this program" hopefully this should get you what you want.
Thanks

You can see this in XP by opening Windows Explorer, clicking Tools, selecting Folder Options, then going to the tab marked File Types. This lets you change a file association to a different program

Source 
http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/askjack/2011/mar/10/zip-files-windows-vista

Comment: And what should I select for "choose default for this program" ? I want firefox to open the file as a .text file inside it. If I choose firefox, then your solution does not work at all, like the comment above. I wish people would at least try what they suggest first.